# Fiddler Extension DLL in VB.NET can't work

Tags: vb.net, dll

Now, I'm studying programming with VS2010 for VB,
and trying making Extension DLL for Fiddler.

First I've got a sample code for "AustralianImages/ImageFlipper",
and rewrote it in VB.NET.

Building DLL file has successfully completed (though it was hard)
and copied it to "Fiddler2\Scripts" folder, but Fiddler seems not to
load it.
Using document folder, or changing .net Framework version to 2.0 doesn't work also.

Does anyone have some clues? Thanks.

```
    Public Class MyFlip Implements IAutoTamper

    Private bEnabled As Boolean
    Dim oMenuItem As MenuItem = New MenuItem("M&y Flip")

    #Region "IAutoTamper Members"
    Public Sub OnBeforeReturningError(ByVal oSession As Session) Implements IAutoTamper.OnBeforeReturningError
    End Sub
    Public Sub AutoTamperRequestAfter(ByVal oSession As Session) Implements IAutoTamper.AutoTamperRequestAfter
    End Sub
    Public Sub AutoTamperRequestBefore(ByVal oSession As Session) Implements IAutoTamper.AutoTamperRequestBefore
    End Sub
    Public Sub AutoTamperResponseAfter(ByVal oSession As Session) Implements IAutoTamper.AutoTamperResponseAfter
    End Sub

    Public Sub AutoTamperResponseBefore(ByVal oSession As Session) Implements IAutoTamper.AutoTamperResponseBefore

        If (bEnabled = False) Then Exit Sub

        If oSession.ToString() <> String.Empty _
            And oSession.responseCode = 200 _
            And oSession.oResponse.ToString() <> String.Empty _
            And oSession.oResponse.headers.ToString() & oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/gif").ToString() & _
                oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/png").ToString() & _
                oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/jp").ToString() <> String.Empty Then
            Try
                oSession.utilDecodeResponse()
                Dim oStream = New MemoryStream(oSession.responseBodyBytes)
                Dim oBMP = New Bitmap(oStream)
                oBMP.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)

                Dim oNewStream = New MemoryStream()
                oBMP.Save(oNewStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                oSession.responseBodyBytes = oNewStream.GetBuffer()
                oSession.oResponse.headers("Content-Length") = oSession.responseBodyBytes.Length.ToString()
                oSession.oResponse.headers("Content-Type") = "image/png"
                oSession.oResponse.headers("Cache-Control") = "no-cache"
                oStream.Dispose()
                oNewStream.Dispose()
            Catch eX As Exception
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(eX.ToString(), "ImageFlipper Failed")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "IFiddlerExtension_Members"
    Public Sub OnBeforeUnload() Implements IFiddlerExtension.OnBeforeUnload
        bEnabled = False
        oMenuItem.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnLoad() Implements IFiddlerExtension.OnLoad
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString("MyFlip OnLoad Start.")
        'oMenuItem = New MenuItem("M&y Flip")
        AddHandler oMenuItem.Click, AddressOf oMenuItem_Click

        FiddlerApplication.UI.mnuTools.MenuItems.Add(oMenuItem)
        MsgBox("vbOK!!")
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogString("BB OnLoad End.")
    End Sub
    Sub oMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                   ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        oMenuItem.Checked = Not (oMenuItem.Checked)
        bEnabled = oMenuItem.Checked
    End Sub
    #End Region
    End Class
```

Comment: I bet that's the wrong folder

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this sentence...(´・ω・｀)

```
    <Assembly: Fiddler.RequiredVersion("2.4.6.0")>
```

And,,,,, in fact, the code I wrote has mistranslation at the
oSession condition judgement.

Somebody please don't copy & use my code as it stands.

Thanks a lot.